# Multiple IP's bind to same interface in hyper-V does not respond to telnet or ping

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, telnet, private-ip

I have configured CentOS-6.0 VM in hyper-V. Configured multiple IP and bind to same Network adapter. Below are interfaces created.
ifcfg-eth0 - 10.225.180.96
ifcfg-eth0:1 - 10.225.180.97
ifcfg-eth0:2
...
...
ifcfg-eth0:9

Now, I cannot ping or telnet to any port internally to these private IP's(10.225.180.96,10.225.180.97...). See the image below..There is no iptable rules configured.

No idea or no logs. What is the problem...

[Telnet Not Responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FDg2.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to connect from a computer in the same network (10.225.180.x)?

Comment: I am trying to connect from same computer to itself.

Comment: Can you show your routing table (ip route show)? You have a lot of IP addresses in the same subnet configured. Also, you may wish to run tcpdump (with filter ip host 10.225.180.98) to see which interface the connection is trying to use.

Comment: Destination                         Gateway                Genmask           iface 
10.225.180.96                    0.0.0.0             255.255.255.224      eth0
169.254.0.0                         0.0.0.0            255.255.0.0              eth0
0.0.0.0                               10.225.180.97   0.0.0.0                     eth0

Comment: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
16:28:21.931202 IP 10.225.180.98.ssh > 45.118.183.52.36098: Flags [P.], seq 2293962550:2293962742, ack 3001065430, win 121, options [nop,nop,TS val 1806588708 ecr 940426776], length 192
16:28:21.931522 IP 10.225.180.98.41326 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 51800+ PTR? 52.183.118.45.in-addr.arpa. (44)
16:28:21.931601 IP 45.118.183.52.36098 > 10.225.180.98.ssh: Flags [.], ack 192, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 940426791 ecr 1806588708], length 0

Comment: 16:28:22.110357 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > 10.225.180.98.41326: 51800 NXDomain 0/1/0 (94)
16:28:22.110534 IP 10.225.180.98.38457 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 60861+ PTR? 98.180.225.10.in-addr.arpa. (44)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused as loopback adapter was missing - ifcfg-lo . Manually created ifcfg-lo and enabled lo using the command #ifcfg-lo. Then this got resolved.